# Parent object goes out of scope when I have captured child property - when does it dispose the child property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, decoupling

I wasn't quite sure how to word the question, but to elaborate, I'm using the AWS SDK in my ASP.Net Web API 2 project and I want to return a response stream for an S3 object - the stream is delivered to the client and then disposed.

What I'm unsure about is that my references to S3 are abstracted away into an `IFileStore` object in order to decouple myself from AWS as a dependency. Inside my file store, I retrieve an `S3Response` object which contains a `ResponseStream` property. If the `S3Response` object is disposed, it will dispose the underlying `ResponseStream`. The `IFileStore` only returns a `Stream` though, which I then package up and return from my API as `StreamContent`.

Given that I call `FileStore.GetFile(...)` and it returns the value of the `ResponseStream` property and the `ResponseStream` then goes out of scope, I have a suspicion that `Dispose` will potentially be called on the `ResponseStream` object by its parent during normal GC behaviour before the HTTP response is completed.

How can I keep S3 abstracted away and ensure that the response stream is only disposed of once the HTTP response completes?

One way I could do it would be to package the whole S3 response object into a generic container object which implements `Stream` as a proxy to the underlying stream so that I can then return `StreamContent` from my API method, and then have the `Dispose` method then dispose the entire underlying S3 response object when the framework naturally calls Dispose at the end of the process. Not sure if there's a better way to do it though.

Comment: I think you should be using `PushStreamContent` for this: http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi

Comment: Yep, that was it, thanks! @Noseratio add this as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a good idea to use [`PushStreamContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.pushstreamcontent%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to stream data to the client from ASP.NET Web API. `PushStreamContent` supports asynchronous data-producing lambda (`Func<Task>`), and the client can start receiving the content stream immediately.

Here's a great blog post on the subject, with some sample code: ["Asynchronous Streaming in ASP.NET WebApi"](http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi).

I can't speak for AWS SDK, but ideally you may be able to pump data asynchronously from the stream returned by an AWS API directly to the stream being sent to the client of your Web API.

Comment: Thanks. Worth noting also, that to pump from my source stream to the target stream, I had to use stream.CopyToAsync. The synchronous version of the method seemed to deadlock internally for some reason.